# variance covariance matrix by group

Tags: r, matrix

I am very new at R and am struggling to create a matrix. My eventual goal is to produce a variance covariance matrix comparing 6 numeric variables (columns) by groups. I have 2187 rows of data,  which are divided among to several hundred groups. I tried to create a matrix with variations of the following, using the help(matrix) information. This gives me a matrix that is the correct size, but filled with x,y information based on the structure of the database:

> matrix(data = PhenoM, nrow = 2187, ncol = 6, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL)
>
> ```
>     [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
> ```
>
> [,1] factor,2187 Integer,2187    Integer,2187    Numeric,2187    Numeric,2187    .factor,2187
>
> [,2]    factor,2187     Numeric,2187    Numeric,2187    Numeric,2187    factor,2187     Integer,2187
>
> [,3]   factor,2187     Numeric,2187    Numeric,2187    Numeric,2187    factor,2187     Numeric,2187

I'm also not sure how to instruct R that the 6 columns of information I want in the matrix are the last 6 of 13 (read right to left). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subset your matrix (or data.frame) and use `cov` in base R to create a covariance matrix:

```
cov(PhenoM[1:2187,8:13])
```

Notice I have subset `PhenoM` by the last six columns in a 13 column data structure (i.e., I have selected columns 8 through 13). I recommend learning about R's basic data structures and how to subset them.

Comment: Thank you, that was actually very helpful. I was thinking about some of the code phrasing all wrong.